# Two parameter URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to change URLs with two parameters from:

```
https://www.example.com/single?name=Name-name&id=1
https://www.example.com/compilation?name=Name-name&id=1
https://www.example.com/album?name=Name-name&id=1
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/single/Name-name/1
https://www.example.com/compilation/Name-name/1
https://www.example.com/album/Name-name/1
```

The site is hosted on Centos 6.9 with Apache 2.2.15
I have the following in Virtualhost - Directory

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/example">
Options FollowSymLinks
#Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride All
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #check if not in admin dir
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/

    #1)externally redirect "/file.php" to "/file"   
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

    #2)Internally map "/file" back to "/file.php"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]

    #Rewrite index.php to /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ single?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ compilation?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ album?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i've tried different rewrite rules in different order, with or whitout extension (single.php, compilation.php and album.php) but none of them worked. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last 3 rules in:

```
RewriteRule ^single/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ single?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^compilation/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ compilation?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^album/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ album?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Place them before `#1)externally redirect`...`.
If they use php files (with .php) change to:

```
RewriteRule ^single/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ single.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^compilation/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ compilation.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^album/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ album.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

And to redirect to pretty link, use (before the others) :

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(single|compilation|album)(?:\.php)?\?name=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have changed those 3 lines, i've put them before #externally redirect, but still not working. https://www.example.com/single.php?name=Name&id=1 is rewrited to https://www.example.com/single?name=Name&id=1 (cuts the .php), but does not rewriting to https://example.com/single/Name/1

Comment: I rewrite `example.com/single/Name/1` to actual link

Comment: If i put in the address bar the url manualy (example.com/single/Name/1) it's working, but the css, js and image files are not loading

Comment: it's working if i enter the url manually, resolved with css, js and images by adding <base href="/"> in head. How to redirect automatically to example.com/single/Name/1 ?

Comment: I add that in my answer